# SPARK SQL: Implement AND condition inside a CASE statement

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am aware of how to implement a simple CASE-WHEN-THEN clause in SPARK SQL using Scala. I am using Version 1.6.2. But, I need to specify AND condition on multiple columns inside the CASE-WHEN clause. How to achieve this in SPARK using Scala ?

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Here's the SQL query that I have:

```
select  sd.standardizationId,
   case when sd.numberOfShares = 0 and
             isnull(sd.derivatives,0) = 0 and 
             sd.holdingTypeId not in (3,10)
        then 
             8
        else
             holdingTypeId
       end 
   as holdingTypeId 
from sd;
```

Comment: Does that query work? If not, what error do you get? Don't make us guess. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative option, if it's wanted to avoid using the full string expression, is the following:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val sd = sqlContext.table("sd")

val conditionedColumn: Column = when(
  (sd("numberOfShares") === 0) and
  (coalesce(sd("derivatives"), lit(0)) === 0) and
  (!sd("holdingTypeId").isin(Seq(3,10): _*)), 8
).otherwise(sd("holdingTypeId")).as("holdingTypeId")

val result = sd.select(sd("standardizationId"), conditionedColumn)
```

Answer (score 2):

First read table as dataframe

```
val table = sqlContext.table("sd")
```

Then select with expression. There align syntaxt according to your database.

```
val result = table.selectExpr("standardizationId","case when numberOfShares = 0 and isnull(derivatives,0) = 0 and holdingTypeId not in (3,10) then 8 else holdingTypeId end as holdingTypeId")
```

And show result

```
result.show
```

Comment: Just curious to know, if this is working , the above query in the question also work... right? what is the difference between these two?

Comment: In first example it is used as sql which querying table and creating dataframe (If author used in same way) and it should rise parsing exception  at "not in". In second example the select applied on dataframe which already created from table and there manipulations merely rises parsing exceptions depending on syntax support.